# How to authorize user in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, authorization

What am I building is simple chrome extension which adds my script to all pages user visit like this

in contentscript.js:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://localhost:3000/js/hack.js';
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

on rails-backend there is simple login-password and omniauth(oauth) authorization via `devise` gem.

If I authorize on rails pages and later in `hack.js` I try to make some ajax calls to my local server via `XMLHttpRequest` - it tries its best to assure me that user is not authorized.

I bet it can be solved via opening invisible iframe somewhere, but that's hellova pain, may be there are some more handy methods?

Comment: Why do you need to host that script as opposed to bundling it with the extension?

Comment: @Xan that's a common way to do that because scripts that you ship with your extensions are executed in a special namespace, not actually on the page

Comment: Wrong: if you inject you script using a `<script>` tag it will be executed in page context. You only need to declare the script web-accessible in the manifest.

Comment: @Xan that's exactly what I do. and shipping my script from external server allows me to update it easily

Answer (score 1):

To do an authorized request, you probably have to get your script in an XHR, where you can add various auth headers. Then the script can be [injected as inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/934239) instead of supplying an `src`.

Do note that content scripts can do cross-domain XHR for all sites that have [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) in the manifest, even if the page is not allowed to do it.

Since the page's Content Security Policy can potentially forbid injection of a script with your URL in the `src`, but injecting it as inline script [sort of bypasses CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions), it's a superior method anyway.

Comment: any examples of "to get your script in an XHR, where you can add various auth headers" ?

Comment: Which part? Specific auth scheme? Basic is [something like that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12852667/934239), OAuth - I think the various keys are just encoded in request parameters.